# JavaScript create promise queue without async/await

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, iterable

I am trying to create a so-called "promise queue". The idea is that, so long as there are promises left to be resolved, we can keep adding more promises to the queue.

I am challenging myself to implement this promise queue without using `async/await` syntax, as I would like to see if it is even possible to do so efficiently without this syntax.

The method I attempted is to use `Promise.all` but pass a custom iterable object, which will keep yielding new promises if they come in on time. The problem is, `Promise.all` doesn't lazily iterate the iterable, but rather it iterates the promises all at once at the very beginning.

Any other ideas on how to implement a promise queue efficiently without async/await syntax?

```
class PromiseQueue {
    constructor() {
        this._queue = new Set();
    }

    add(promise) {
        this._queue.add(promise);
    }

    all() {
        let self = this;
        let alreadyIterated = false;

        return Promise.all({
            [Symbol.iterator]: function*() {
                if (alreadyIterated) {
                    console.error("already iterated");
                    throw new Error("already iterated");
                }

                alreadyIterated = true;

                while (true) {
                    let { value: promise, done } = self._queue.values().next();
                    
                    if (done) {
                        return;
                    }
                    
                    self._queue.delete(promise);
                    console.log("deleting");

                    yield promise;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

let createPromise = () => {
    let resolve, reject;
    let promise = new Promise((resolve_, reject_) => {
        resolve = resolve_;
        reject = reject_;
    });

    return [promise, resolve, reject];
}

let timeout = (ms) => {
    let [promise, resolve, _reject] = createPromise();
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    return promise;
};

let queue = new PromiseQueue();
queue.add(timeout(1000));

setTimeout(() => {
    queue.add(timeout(1000));   
    queue.add(timeout(1000));
}, 500);

let result = await queue.all();
console.log(result);
```

Comment: The whole idea of promises is that they are capable of resolving asynchronously. If you want to resolve them synchronously (ala with a queue) you should use either `await` or promise.then

Comment: @ControlAltDel How can I implement PromiseQueue with `.then`? Nothing comes to mind.

Comment: @JeffBowman Yes, and apparently I had already viewed that question and upvoted answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is updated `PromiseQueue` implementation inspired from the other answer.

```
class PromiseQueue {
    constructor() {
        this._queue = [];
    }

    add(promise) {
        this._queue.push(promise);
    }

    all() {
        return this._all([]);
    }

    _all(results) {
        let all = Promise.all(this._queue);
        this._queue = [];

        return all.then((newResults) => {
            results.push(...newResults);

            if (this._queue.length > 0) {
                return this._all(results);
            }

            return results;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
all() {
  var iterator = this._queue.values();
  function iterate() {
    let v = iterator.next();
    if (!v.done) {
      return v.value.then(iterate);
    }
  }
  return Promise.resolve(iterate());
}
```

Comment: I was thinking something like that would be inefficient, but it actually looks like the best possible solution, thanks